# how to set a variable in sql if null or blank value exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
set val=isnull(FLD380,'Null')
```

***i need to write same statement for SPACE(''). *like this***

```
 set val=space(FLD380,'Space')
```

Comment: Is this for MySQL or for SQL-Server? Please clarify because it matters and the answers can differ.

Comment: i am using ms-sqlserver

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're *specifically* asking for is a [user-defined function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186755.aspx). Note this syntax is for SQL Server.

```
CREATE FUNCTION IsSpace (
  @check_expression NVARCHAR(max),
  @replacement_value NVARCHAR(max)
)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
BEGIN
  IF @check_expression = N''
    RETURN @replacement_value

  RETURN @check_expression
END
```

Which can be called like this:

```
set @val = IsSpace(FLD380, N'Space')
```

Alternatively, here's the SQL Server syntax for Explosion Pills' response.

```
SET @val =
  CASE
    WHEN FLD380 = '' THEN 'Space'
    ELSE ISNULL(FLD380, 'null')
  END
```

Comment: MySQL does not have `NVARCHAR` datatype.

Comment: @ypercube - It's unclear whether Shakeel is on MySql or SqlServer (both are specified). Given that he hit a syntax error using MySql syntax (see below), it's pretty safe to assume he's on SqlServer.

Comment: Oh, you are probably right. I didn't read carefully. the `ISNULL()` function is a +1 on your assumption, too. I would add (the SQL-Server assumption) in the answer, too.

Answer (score 1):

```
SET val= CASE WHEN FLD380 = '' THEN 'Space' ELSE 
(CASE WHEN FLD380 IS NULL THEN 'Null' END) END
```

[See fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7d7c6/2)

Comment: `WHEN FLD380 = NULL` should be `WHEN FLD380 IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

```
SET val = IF(FLD380 = '', 'Space', IFNULL(FLD380, 'Null'))
```

Comment: it contains syntax err @expolsion plus

Comment: @SHAKEELHUSSAIN - This syntax is setup for MySql and it will compile without error.

Answer (score 0):

how about using `COALESCE`

```
SET val = IF(TRIM(FLD380) = '', 'SPACE', COALESCE(FLD380, 'NULL'))
```